# Check if a value is equal with another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code that should loop through an array of objects and if the `name` value is repeated anywhere in array, the code should display "repeatedName". If not "not repeatedName".

```js
export default function App() {
  const arr = [
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: "Julia",
      age: 28
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: "Bill",
      age: 22
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((i, k) => (
        <p>
          {arr[k + 1] !== undefined && i.name === arr[k + 1].name
            ? "repeatedName"
            : "not repeatedName"}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Now i get this:

```css
not repeatedName

not repeatedName

not repeatedName

not repeatedName
```

But the expected result is:

```css
not repeatedName

not repeatedName

repeatedName

not repeatedName
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-shaw-0mdxi?file=/src/App.js:450-462
How to change my code to get the described result?

Comment: By looking at the code, I understand that you are evaluating if the _name in the current index_ is the same as the _name on the immediate following index_.
That condition would be true if for instance, array element 0 has the name **John** and array element 1 also has it. For your specific array, this condition is never met

Comment: Your problem statement is to identify *adjacent* names that are the same. Your code is doing that. Is your problem statement incorrect?

Comment: Your code appears to do exactly as you describe you wanted. I guess you actually want it to say `repeatedName` if the name has previously appeared *anywhere* in the array?

Comment: @Robin Sigmund, if the name is repeated anywhere in array I should display repeatedName instead of that name.

Comment: Actually your code is still wrong for how you described it, because it checks against the *next* name instead of the previous, and will always say no repeat for the last.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond, how to fix it?

Comment: You could always create a second array of unique names and check if the name is in that array

Comment: @terrymorse, , if the name is repeated anywhere in array I should display repeatedName instead of that name.

Comment: Webb, could you show, please?

Comment: I've corrected your problem statement and added an alternative method using `Set`, below.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the duplicates, you will need to store the unique names in another array, then reference that array within the loop of the object.

The following will loop through the object and add the name of the person to the array. Then when it continues through the loop, the name is checked with names we already know about.

```js
const uniqueNames = []
const people = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Julia",
    age: 28
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    age: 22
  }
]

people.forEach((person) => {
  if (uniqueNames.indexOf(person.name) > -1) {
    console.log('Repeated')
    return
  }
  uniqueNames.push(person.name)
  console.log('Not repeated')
})
```

Comment: I your case I won't have access to the age key. Probably I did not explained correctly.  Even I will output notRepeted or Repeatedl I want to have access also and to age key.

Comment: This is an example of how to know if the name is repeated. You will have to modify this code to fit your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on the task (just for the heck of it):
(Carl's solution is a more elegant one)

```
  const arr = [
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: "Julia",
      age: 28
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: "Bill",
      age: 22
    }
  ];


  return (
    <div className="App">

      {arr.map((i,k)=>{

          const isFound = k-1 > 0 && arr.slice(0, k-1).some( el => {
            return el.name === i.name; 
          })
          return isFound ? <p>repeatedName</p> : <p>not repeatedName</p>
      })}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @KostaX, I your case I won't have access to the age key. Probably I did not explained correctly.  Even I will output notRepeted or Repeatedl I want to have access also and to age key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check if the name previously appeared anywhere in the array, you *can* do this with `map` - but it's going to look fairly clumsy and inelegant:

```
{arr.map((i, k) => (
    <p>
      {arr[k - 1] !== undefined && arr.slice(0, k).some(obj => obj.name === arr[k].name) 
        ? "repeatedName"
        : "not repeatedName"}
    </p>
))}
```

Although I am in general a fan of the "functional style" using `map` and so on, here I think it's more appropriate to use a more imperative style with a loop and some internal state:

```
const getRepeatedStates = arr => {
    const names = [];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const currentName = arr[i].name;
        result.push(names.includes(currentName) ? "repeatedName" : "not repeatedName";
        names.push(currentName);
    } 
    return result;
}
```

And then in your returned JSX, use

```
{getRepeatedStates(arr).map(text => (<p>{text}</p>)}
```

Comment: I your case I won't have access to the age key. Probably I did not explained correctly.  Even I will output notRepeted or Repeatedl I want to have access also and to age key.

Comment: You're right that you never mentioned this - no ages are mentioned in either your actual output or your desired output. However it's easy to fix, since in the loop version you can still access the age in each loop iteration, and rather than just add the string indicating repeat or not, add an object with that and the age.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy JavaScript object that makes it very easy to identify duplicates like these.

It's called [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Use `Set.prototype.add()` to add to the set, and `Set.prototype.has()` to determine if a value is in the set. A value can exist only once in a Set.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "John", age: 22 },
  { name: "Julia", age: 28 },
  { name: "John", age: 22 },
  { name: "Bill", age: 22 }
];

const nameSet = new Set();
let nameStats = arr.map(el => {
  let status = nameSet.has(el.name) ?
    "repeatedName" : "not repeatedName";
  nameSet.add(el.name);
  return status;
});

console.log('nameStats:', nameStats);
```